# three.js color of object, not texture

Tags: colors, three.js, textures

So to explain the weird title first, I am trying to make a 3D avatar for a little project I am working on, however when I try to change the color of the arm on the avatar, it doesn't actually change the color with the texture on it, it changes the color of the white part (not transparent) of the texture, but where it is transparent on the texture it shows white with, as it seems, no lighting.

**Before coloring:**

[image]

**After coloring:**

[image]

The actual texture I am using can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txCKH.jpg

This is how I am rendering the texture:

```
var AvatarTexture = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./images/Shirt/vest.png'), shininess: 80, shading: THREE.SmoothShading, alphaMap: 0x000000} );
```

and the coloring:

```
object.children[0].material.color.setHex(0xffcc66);
object.children[2].material.color.setHex(0xffcc66);
object.children[4].material.color.setHex(0xffcc66);
```

the object itself is a UV mapped .obj exported from blender. This happens even if the texture does not have transparency.

Comment: You changing color of entire material. Mixing of color. But if you mix white with color, result is another than blue body. There is blue + yellow = green.

Answer (score 1):

First, in three.js, the final color is the product of `material.color` and `material.map`, component-wise.

So if you change `material.color`, the final texture color will be tinted.

Second, if two meshes share the same material, and you change the material color, then both meshes will change color.

To prevent that, you need to have a separate material instance for each mesh.

```
material2 = material1.clone();
```

three.js r.77

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change color of part, it is not important an object, but a material **var reference**.

```
    //your solution as i understand question

var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( .. );

    var mesh1.material = material1;
    var mesh2.material = material1;

material1.color= red; // both meshes change color.


//solution:

var mesh1.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( .. );
var mesh2.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( .. );

//or

var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( .. );
var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( .. );

var mesh1.material = material1;
var mesh2.material = material2;
```

Comment: So, how does this change the color of the parts? I tried adding it inline with the MeshPhongMaterial however it just did the same thing.

Comment: I don't know how your model is separated, what is the meaning of the part, but yes, if it is left hand child of object with index=0 (or etc), than object.children[0].material.color.setHex(0xffcc66);is applied only on the hand. You can switch material by another reference than a mesh. for example material1.color.setHex(0xffcc66); will works too.

Comment: The issue is that it is coloring the texture, not the mesh. The hand stays pure white, regardless of the color I make it. However, if I do not have a texture on it at all, the hand is colored fine, not white.

Comment: you are not coloring a mesh, but a material. Texture color is calculated by the material color. if you want to have material only with color, not a texture, remove the texture from the mesh.material. I think you bad understand the material behavior. See the material Blending and transparency behavior http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_blending.html